# Regex loses last character

Tags: regex, python-3.x

My regex is `(?<![\u0410-\u042F])[.!?](?=(\s)?(\s)?[\u0410-\u042F]|[\u04E8]|["]|[\u201C]|![0-9])`

I want to split a paragraph into sentences.

I do the regex with re.split() and I print the array

This is a sample input I did:

`Мамлекеттик айыптоочу Биринчи май райондук сотуна берген бул сунушун диний кастыкты ырбатпоо аракети менен негиздеди. Мусулмандарга акаарат келтирип жатат деген кайрылуу каттын негизинде УКМК Тезекбаевге каршы кылмыш ишин козгоп, сотко өткөргөн. Бул ишти бүгүн Биринчи май райондук соту карап бүттү жана өкүм эртең чыгарыларын маалымдады. Тараптар мунаса тапты;
Ишти карап жаткан мамлекеттик айыптоочу Кудайберди Чаргынов Кубанычбек Тезекбаевдин диний кастыкты козутууга болгон аракети толугу менен далилденгенин билдирүүдө. Бирок мамлекеттик айыптоочу диний кастыкты ырбатпоо максатында Кыргызстандын Кылмыш кодексинин 65-беренесине ылайык, иш өз маанисин жоготконуна байланыштуу кылмыш ишин Т.У. кыскартып салууну сунуштады.`

It prints out fine except that the last character (in this case a period, ?, or !) gets removed!

I searched online and it says to surround the punctuation with lookahead tags, but it doesn't work.

I'm using Python 3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put a capturing group around the character(s) you want to preserve in the split:

```
(?<![\u0410-\u042F])([.!?])(?=(\s)?(\s)?[\u0410-\u042F]|[\u04E8]|["]|[\u201C]|![0-9])
```

The periods will be added as new elements in the resulting list. From the [documentation](http://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.split):

> If capturing parentheses are used in pattern, then the text of all groups in the pattern are also returned as part of the resulting list.

If you don't want this, you'll have to split on the space itself, by ensuring that the space is *preceded* by a matching period of other punctuation marks (using a look-behind assertion).

Comment: But that puts the period on a new line :(

Comment: @user1925847: you can merge that back into the previous line, or use a different expression to split on, namely the space.